# Different integral values for analytically same integrals

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, numerical-integration, integral-equations

Consider a function $L$ with parameters $h=0.1,\ D=1.5$

$L(m,x):=e^{-\frac{2\ (\frac{x}{h}-m)^{2}}{D}}$.

While the integrals $\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}L(0,x)dx$ and $\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}L(40,x)dx$ are same analytically, Mathematica is giving different values which are 0.153499 and 0, respectively.

The code

```
ah=0.1;
aD=1.5;        
L[n_] := Function[x, Exp[-2*(x - n*ah)^2/(aD*ah^2)]]
Integrate[L[0][x], {x, -Infinity, Infinity}]
Integrate[L[40][x], {x, -Infinity, Infinity}]
```

Comment: The problem is that you use `Integrate` to a function with noninteger numbers. Then Mathematica returns the error message explaining what's wrong. Have a look. Use `NIntegrate` instead.

Comment: This integral can be done in closed-form without choosing any numerical values, and the result does NOT depend on `n`. This is because you are integrating a Gaussian profile over an infinite range, so the `n`-dependent position of the Gaussian "hump" does not matter.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The integral of L[40] gives a warning that precision may be lost because of small numbers.

[image]

Therefore what you can do is to use exact numbers like:

```
ah = 1/10;
aD = 15/10;
L[n_] := Function[x, Exp[-2*(x - n*ah)^2/(aD*ah^2)]]
Integrate[L[0][x], {x, -Infinity, Infinity}]
Integrate[L[40][x], {x, -Infinity, Infinity}]
```

[image]